# 32 - битный С и 32 - битный Assembler

Tags: c, ассемблер, ос

Из следующего 32-ух битного кода ассемблера вызывается C-функция kernel_start() (файл loader1.asm):

```
bits 32
global start1
extern kernel_start

start1:

mov AH, 0x09
mov AL, 0x21
mov CX, 0x01
mov BH, 0x00
mov BL, 0x0F

int 0x10

mov AH, 0x00
mov AL, 0x03

int 0x10

cli
call kernel_start
hlt
```

Код C (файл kernel.c):

```
void kernel_start() {
 char *video_memory = (char*)0xb8000;

 for(int i = 0; i < 80 * 25 * 2; i+=2) {
  video_memory[i] = '!';
  video_memory[i + 1] = 0x0F;
 }
}
```

Собирается всё с помощью следующих команд:

```
nasm -f elf32 loader1.asm -o loader1.o
gcc -m32 -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
ld -m elf_i386 -T link.ld -o kernel loader1.o kernel.o
```

link.ld:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
ENTRY(start1)
SECTIONS {
 . = 0x00000000;
 .text : { *(.text)}
 .data : { *(.data)}
 .bss : { *(.bss)}
}
```

Запускается kernel из другого (16-бит) ассемблерного файла. Но kernel не работает и kernel_start(), соответственно, не запускается. Что делать?

**UPD**

dump2 - 32 bit dump - 16 bit

```
objdump -y dump2 dump
kernel:     формат файла elf32-i386             kernel:     формат файла elf32-i386


Дизассемблирование раздела .text:               Дизассемблирование раздела .text:

00000000 <start1>:                      00000000 <start1>:
   0:   b4 00                   mov    ah,0x0              0:   b4 00                   mov    ah,0x0
   2:   b0 03                   mov    al,0x3              2:   b0 03                   mov    al,0x3
   4:   cd 10                   int    0x10            4:   cd 10                   int    0x10
   6:   b4 09                   mov    ah,0x9              6:   b4 09                   mov    ah,0x9
   8:   b0 21                   mov    al,0x21             8:   b0 21                   mov    al,0x21
   a:   66 b9 01 00             mov    cx,0x1              a:   66 b9 01 00             mov    cx,0x1
   e:   b7 00                   mov    bh,0x0              e:   b7 00                   mov    bh,0x0
  10:   b3 0f                   mov    bl,0xf             10:   b3 0f                   mov    bl,0xf
  12:   cd 10                   int    0x10           12:   cd 10                   int    0x10
  14:   fa                      cli                   14:   fa                      cli    
  15:   e8 01 00 00 00          call   1b <kernel_start>      15:   e8 01 00 00 00          call   1b <kernel_start>
  1a:   f4                      hlt                   1a:   f4                      hlt    

0000001b <kernel_start>:                    0000001b <kernel_start>:
  1b:   55                      push   ebp            |   1b:   66 55                   push   bp
  1c:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp            |   1d:   66 89 e5                mov    bp,sp
  1e:   83 ec 10                sub    esp,0x10           |   20:   66 83 ec 10             sub    sp,0x10
  21:   c7 45 fc 00 80 0b 00    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x |   24:   67 66 c7 45 fc 00 80    mov    WORD PTR [di-0x4],0x80
  28:   c7 45 f8 00 00 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],0x |   2b:   0b 00                   or     eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
  2f:   eb 1d                   jmp    4e <kernel_start+0x33> |   2d:   67 66 c7 45 f8 00 00    mov    WORD PTR [di-0x8],0x0
  31:   8b 55 f8                mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8 |   34:   00 00                   add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
  34:   8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4 |   36:   eb 2d                   jmp    65 <kernel_start+0x4a>
  37:   01 d0                   add    eax,edx            |   38:   67 66 8b 55 f8          mov    dx,WORD PTR [di-0x8]
  39:   c6 00 21                mov    BYTE PTR [eax],0x21    |   3d:   67 66 8b 45 fc          mov    ax,WORD PTR [di-0x4]
  3c:   8b 45 f8                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8 |   42:   66 01 d0                add    ax,dx
  3f:   8d 50 01                lea    edx,[eax+0x1]          |   45:   67 c6 00 21             mov    BYTE PTR [bx+si],0x21
  42:   8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4 |   49:   67 66 8b 45 f8          mov    ax,WORD PTR [di-0x8]
  45:   01 d0                   add    eax,edx            |   4e:   67 66 8d 50 01          lea    dx,[bx+si+0x1]
  47:   c6 00 0f                mov    BYTE PTR [eax],0xf     |   53:   67 66 8b 45 fc          mov    ax,WORD PTR [di-0x4]
  4a:   83 45 f8 02             add    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],0x |   58:   66 01 d0                add    ax,dx
  4e:   81 7d f8 9f 0f 00 00    cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8],0x |   5b:   67 c6 00 0f             mov    BYTE PTR [bx+si],0xf
  55:   7e da                   jle    31 <kernel_start+0x16> |   5f:   67 66 83 45 f8 02       add    WORD PTR [di-0x8],0x2
  57:   90                      nop               |   65:   67 66 81 7d f8 9f 0f    cmp    WORD PTR [di-0x8],0xf9
  58:   c9                      leave                 |   6c:   00 00                   add    BYTE PTR [eax],al
  59:   c3                      ret                   |   6e:   7e c8                   jle    38 <kernel_start+0x1d>
                                  >   70:   90                      nop
                                  >   71:   c9                      leave  
                                  >   72:   c3                      ret
```

Comment: А в отладчике что?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов в смысле в дизассемблере?

Comment: В смысле в отладчике что видите в момент передачи управления на сишную функцию.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов мне не удается запустить kernel через GDB.

Comment: http://os.phil-opp.com/multiboot-kernel.html Возможно поможет чем-то. И ещё вот это: https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/Booting/linux-bootstrap-1.html